# What is the use case of text attribute inside ImageView Android( it won't show up any way)?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I notice that for Android ImageView there is an attribute which is `android:text = "Hello"`, but when I run the code, I can't see the text, I'm wondering why there is a text attribute if you can't see it. Do I miss something on how to use it? I'm thinking it can be used to help automation testing, when user switch drawable and text for the ImageView, automation code can compare the text to see if certain image is displayed or not.

Comment: Why do you think it has a text attribute?  Did you see it in a layout?  You can put whatever attributes you want in an xml file, attributes it doesn't use are ignored and dropped

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be putting text in an ImageView like that. If you want to display text, just use a `TextView`. Just because you can put the attribute doesn't mean it's useful for something.

Answer (score 1):

Android ImageView is a child of View class. So it doesn't have a property called text. However, while editing the layout manually, you can add it. It'll have no impact. If you try to set the text programmatically or through attributes window, you'll not be able to. It gives you a compilation error.

so don't use text attribute in imageview